# Using Promise.all() with rxjs epics in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, rxjs, es6-promise

I need a solution to return one single promise from 3 different API calls. Currently running 3 different API calls via rxjs epics and looking to return one single promise object after all 3 calls are complete. Having trouble understanding how to use Promise.all() and where to call it. I think something similar to Promise.all() is forkJoin(). I have some dummy data for the example of my epic that I'm using below. This is all happening in React. Could someone please provide an in-depth example of how to use Promise.all() or forkJoin with epics in React please?

Thanks

```
  action$.ofType(GET_PROMISE).mergeMap(
    action =>
      action.payload.search_location === undefined ||
      action.payload.search_location.length === 0 ||
      action.payload.search_location === "" ||
      stateRegex.test(action.payload.search_location.toLowerCase()) === true
      ? api
         .fetchPromise(action.payload)
         .map(
           payload =>
           payload.value === undefined || payload.value.length === 0
                 ? getPromiseFail()
                 : getPromiseSuccess(payload)
           )
```

At the moment, when I get the promise object back, I'm updating state and concatting that data with two other promises from 2 different API calls. Since they are async they are coming back at different times. So I would like to combine all 3 calls before displaying any data in the web application.

Answer (score 0):

You're right to look into [forkJoin](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/forkJoin/).

Heres a rough rewrite of your example:

```js
action$.ofType(GET_PROMISE).mergeMap(
  action =>
    // wait for all three fetches to complete
    forkJoin(
      api.fetchOne(action.payload),
      api.fetchTwo(action.payload),
      api.fetchThree(action.payload)
    )
    // now we have all three results as an array here:
    .map(([one, two, three]) => {
      // turn those results into an action
      return getPromiseSuccess(one, two, three)
    })
)
```

*Please note that the code you've shared seem to use an outdated version of RxJS, so an upgrade or at least [writing code](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/pipe/) in [pipeable form](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators) is advised.*

Hope this helps